# Found a SQL error and I don't know what to do

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am just a beginner who need a little help with this SQL syntax error. Thank you!

Code:

```
use influencersv2;
CREATE TABLE Articles (
  Articles_Id int auto_increment not null,
  Articles_Authors_Id int not null,
  Articles_Tag_Id int not null,
  Articles_Date DateTime not null,
  Articles_Title varchar(250) not null,
  Articles_Content mediumtext not null,
  Articles_Image varbinary(max) null,
  Articles_Edit BIT  not null,
  Articles_Votes int not null,
);
```

Error :

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'max) null,
  Articles_Edit BIT  not null,
  Articles_Votes int not null...' at line 8
```

Comment: `varbinary(max)` - what is max supposed to be? replace it with a number, if you want the max that varbinary actually supports, then check your database's documentation (different databases may have different max lengths for varbinary, but i can't think of a way to find that max length at runtime, short of bruteforcing - 65535 or 255 is my best guess though)

Comment: Thank you @hanshenrik ! I just replaced max with 8000 and it solved it !

Comment: (Please don't prefix column names with the table name; it is clutter.)

Comment: `varbinary(max)` --> `MEDIUMBLOB`.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum allowed rowsize is 65535 bytes, including all your columns, unless you use BLOB or TEXT as one of your column types.
Since you already have a couple of columns and a rather big 250 wide Varchar, they all reduce the maximum remaining space for your Varbinary.
What practically remains for your Varbinary is 65248 bytes.

This works:

```
CREATE or replace TABLE Articles (
  Articles_Id int auto_increment not null,
  Articles_Authors_Id int not null,
  Articles_Tag_Id int not null,
  Articles_Date DateTime not null,
  Articles_Title varchar(250) not null,
  Articles_Content mediumtext not null,
  Articles_Image VARBINARY(65248) null,
  Articles_Edit BIT  not null,
  Articles_Votes int not NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Articles_Id)
);
```

MariaDB will not find out this value for you automatically.

Comment: "The maximum allowed rowsize is 65535 bytes" -- This is a common misconception.

Comment: There is no good reason to use `VARBINARY(65248)` instead of `BLOB` or `MEDIUMBLOB`.